# Meu carousel não troca as imagens Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Simplesmente não troca as imagens do carousel!

```
    <div id="carouselSite" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel"> 
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carouselSite" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselSite" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselSite" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>


        <div class="carousel-inner">

            <div class="carousel-item active">

                <img src="img/lanchonete/slide1.jpg" class="img-fluid d-block">
            </div>

            <div class="carousel-item">

                <img src="img/lanchonete/slide2.jpg" class="img-fluid d-block">
            </div>

            <div class="carousel-item">

                <img src="img/lanchonete/slide3.jpg" class="img-fluid d-block">
            </div>

        </div>

          <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselSite" role="button" data-slide="prev">
              <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Anterior
              </span>

           </a>
           <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselSite" role="button" data-slide="next">
              <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Proximo
              </span>
       </a>
  </div>
```

Comment: Boa noite, Renan. Você lembrou de referenciar o arquivo bootstrap.js ou bootstrap.min.js ao seu projeto. Pois o Carosel é necessário um destes arquivos, como dito na documentação do Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara vc pode ter dois problemas. Reparei que vc está usando a classe `img-fluid` essa classe está errada, vc deveria usar `w-100` para deixar as imagens com 100% da largura.

Depois vc tem que conferir se está chamando o jQuery antes do JSs do Bootstrap. Repare o seu código funcionando perfeitamente nesse exemplo. Só retire `img-fluid`  e coloquei `w-100` e chamei os arquivos dos scripts na ordem correta.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"  />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="carouselSite" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel"> 
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carouselSite" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselSite" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselSite" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>


    <div class="carousel-inner">

        <div class="carousel-item active">

            <img src="http://unsplash.it/600/280" class="img-fluid d-block w-100">
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-item">

            <img src="http://unsplash.it/601/280" class="img-fluid d-block w-100">
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-item">

            <img src="http://unsplash.it/602/280" class="img-fluid d-block w-100">
        </div>

    </div>

      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselSite" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Anterior
          </span>

       </a>
       <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselSite" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Proximo
          </span>
   </a>
</div>
```

**OBS:** Certifique-se também de qual versão do Bootstrap vc está usando e se não está usando o código de uma versão com os JSs de outra versão.

Comment: Eu tinha esquecido mesmo cara, muito obrigado.

Comment: @RenanF.Andrade que bom que deu certo ai. Sempre que fizer uma pergunta aqui no site e tiver uma resposta que te atende e que tenha resolvido seu problema considere marca-la como aceita clicando no ✔ ao lado das setas da resposta que vc escolher.

Comment: opa, valeu, sou novo aqui, nao sei como funciona direito, mas ja fiz o procedimento valeu cara

Comment: @RenanF.Andrade tranquilo jovem! A gente está aqui para aprender e para ensinar tb :) Não é bom deixar perguntas já respondidas e com respostas aceitas abertas, pois o sistema fica colocando ela na lista de perguntas não respondidas, mesmo já tendo uma resposta correta, por isso é indicado marcar o ✔ quando a resposta tiver te atendido.

Answer (score -1):

Comigo funcionou consertando a posição do fechamento das DIVS

```
    </nav>
        <div id="carouselSite" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active ">
                <img src="img/01.jpg" class="img-fluid d-block "></div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="img/02.jpg" class="img-fluid d-block "></div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="img/03.jpg" class="img-fluid d-block "></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselSite" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
        </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselSite" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
        </a>
```

Ricardo Galante

```
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

No site Layout It existem modelos que você pode baixar e conferir. Salve-o em uma pasta chamada LayoutIt para você não se perder. O arquivo vem zipado com CSS, Bootstrap, JQuery.

https://www.layoutit.com

Ao entrar clique em Bootstrap Buider.
No menu da esquerda clique em JavaScript e selecione carousel.
Arraste para o centro da página
No menu superior clique em download para visualizar o código que você pode copiar ou baixar completo que vem com bootstrap, java, css.